# TFS Build definition - add step to run DacPac for Unit Tests

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing, tfs, build

We are using an on-premise installation of **Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 16.131**.

We have a Development Continuous integration build definition that includes running some unit-tests on a very old application. As such, the unit-tests require a database to run (I know, not an ideal situation with unit tests...)

One of the artifacts of the build is a DACPAC of the database.

I'd like to deploy any database changes from that DACPAC as part of the build definition, before running the Unit-Test steps. That way, any tests that are added / changed that are dependent on database changes will (hopefully) pass.

Any ideas if this is possible, and if so, how can I publish from the DACPAC within the build definition?

Comment: If they require a database, then they're **not** unit tests. They are integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a PowerShell step in the build/release pipeline.
In the powershell script you will call SqlPackage:

```
&"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"Dacpac_Artifact\DACPAC\DB.dacpac" /Profile:"Dacpac_Artifact\DACPAC\FileWithPublishPrife.publish.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at this Microsoft DevLabs task, it also contains a sub task to deploy dacpac remotely, so you could deploy to another machine (or use localhost to deploy on the build server itself if you want).  There are also other marketplace task you could use just [navigate to the store](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sql&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance) and type sql you'll see a dozen.

[IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp)